# What famous writer said, "to accurately (or precisely) say how things are is to be truly revolutionary?"

Tags: quote-source

The extended version is something like this: "to accurately say how things are (or how the world is) is to be truly revolutionary, to say how things (or how the world) should be merely reactionary." Or "to accurately see things as they really are is to be truly revolutionary..." Who wrote this? I remember reading it long ago but I'm at a loss as to who wrote it. I've searched Orwell, Marx, Matthew Arnold, Wilde, Rousseau, Nietzsche, and a few others. Can't find it.

Comment: George Orwell wrote “we have now sunk to a depth at which the restatement of the obvious is the first duty of intelligent men” (reviewing Bertrand Russell's book in 1939), is that close to what you had in mind?